# Type error: Object is possibly 'null'. TS2531 for window.document

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I am adding TypeScript to my project for the first time.

Using `window.document.getElementById()` to access something results in the error:

```bash
Type error: Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531
```

I searched online but couldn't come to the best solution for this. `window` can never be null.

Comment: Are you sure that `window` is the only one which is null?

Comment: Ahh, got the issue now. it was for the possibility of the element being null. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 76, accepted):

TS is doing its job and tells you that `window.document.getElementById("foobar")` COULD return something that is `null`.

If you are absolutely sure that `#foobar` element DOES exist in your DOM, you can show TS your confidence with a `!` operator.

```
// Notice the "!" at the end of line
const myAbsolutelyNotNullElement = window.document.getElementById("foobar")!
```

Or, you can add a runtime nullable check to make TS happy

```
const myMaybeNullElement = window.document.getElementById("foobar")

myMaybeNullElement.nodeName // <- error!

if (myMaybeNullElement === null) {
  alert('oops');
} else {
  // since you've done the nullable check
  // TS won't complain from this point on
  myMaybeNullElement.nodeName // <- no error
}
```

Comment: Thank you! TS was giving a valid error. I just didnt realise it was for the element and not the window..

Answer (score 8):

`window.document.getElementById("foobar");`

Is either returning a `HTMLElement` or `null`

As you might used a similar statement before: `window.document.getElementById("foobar").value`

Typescript is complaining about, that value might not be accessible and you should explicitly check this before.

To avoid this you can do the following:

```
const element = window.document.getElementById("foobar");

if (element !== null) {
    alert(element.value);
}
```

Comment: capturing this in a variable worked for me, as using the ! is not an option because that really defeats the purpose of strict mode.  also strict mode also have the "forbidden non null assertion" rule to stop the use of !

Answer (score 4):

It is because you have to set the type.

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById("toggleFilter") as HTMLInputElement
checkbox.checked = true
```

Comment: This is really no different than using `!`. You're still forcing the compiler to ignore the possibility of null.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have to make sure your `window.document.getElementById("id_name")!` is set. You can try this

```
const element = window.document.getElementById("id_name")!;

if(element){
 console.log(element);
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to use the `!` and then check for null.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is complaining that object, result of `window.document.getElementById` execution in your case, can be null.

This could be turned off using [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) flag in your `tsconfig.json` which I do not recommend.

Alternatively you can do checks at suggested in other answers or starting with Typescript 3.7 use [Optional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) syntax to make your code more concise:

```
obj?.doSometething(); //good, will not do something.
obj?.prop = 'plop'; //not good because it does not work with assignments.
```